# Create an user-control from another thread

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I wish to create a button ( made by me as a user-control ) from another thread other than the one i wish to create on . The thing is that i know how to modify a user-control object from another thread ( using a delegate and .InvokeRequired ) but i don't know how i could create one . Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
// From the other thread

userControl11.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
{
    var button = new Button();

    button.Text = "My new button";

    userControl11.Controls.Add(button);
}));
```

Within the delegate (the `() => { }`), you can do anything you like with the user control and the form.

Comment: in my Winforms i've included in a function that i call from the thread.. in it i've included the following code : panel6.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                controlAtentionare ca = new controlAtentionare(data, severitate, locatie, alarma, descriere, true);
                ca.Location = new Point(0, this.Controls.Count * ca.Height);
                this.panel6.Controls.Add(ca);
                MessageBox.Show("LALA");

            }));

Comment: The "lala" alert is displayed but my control isn't added

Comment: Genius! Awesome in place solution. In some cases I hate creating extra methods for invoking even if its a small process. Thanks a lot, learned something new :).

Comment: will this  ``var myCtl  = new customControlTakes10seconds();`` will it not block  gui?? if its inside  begin invoke

Comment: Yes. Invoke means it's executed on the UI thread and wait for completion. You'll block both the UI and the calling thread.

Answer (score 2):

Please read my previous post:

[why isn't user-control class access not safe from another thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155560/why-isnt-user-control-class-access-not-safe-from-another-thread/4155650#4155650)

Control Threading:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Use the same way as for modifying a user control. Function that creates a control must be executed in UI thread, and called using Invoke or BeginInvoke. Pass all information required for control creation using delegate parameters.